# spacemacs: How can I disable flymake and flycheck completely, to speed up performance

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck, ess, flymake

I’m using `spacemacs`. I just installed `syntax-highlighting` layer and `auto-completion` layer, and now my emacs got really really slow.

So slow that going back to PyCharm (IntelliJ) with R-plugin feels waaay better again. initially, emacs had felt better with more freedom, after having slugged through IntelliJ for a few weeks.

The issue is that after installing: polymode, flycheck, autocompletion, poly-r, just to get rmarkdown support, the entire emacs for ESS (R) just feels like a complete slug. Like, 0.5X performance of IntelliJ (on a good day).

I am wondering if any tips on how to disable completely, FlyCheck and FlyMake?  I used `SPC t s` to toggle off FlyCheck, that helped a bit, but FlyMake still is slugging it in the background and highlighting my lines of code.

I really appreciate someone kindly developing a nice lintr for Emacs, but it really slows me down more than just eye-balling the code myself, at this point, in Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to using command SPC SPC then search for FlyMake Mode and select it. Selecting it will toggle the mode on or off. Spacemacs makes finding commands simple by filtering down the list of commands as you type it in. For example, do SPC SPC then type fly. It will filter all commands that have "fly" in it's name. You might need to do this time to time for commands that you do not know the exact name for.

SPC SPC is equivalent to the M-x command in plain emacs editor. You can execute any command you want in your emacs environment here. All modes will have a command to toggle them and ussually with it has word "mode" in the command. Spacemacs will also list key bindings to the commands here. If FlyMake Mode Command has a keybinding you will know what to type to execute it next time.

Comment: thanks for the info!